# error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<std::string, int> &>'

Tags: c++, c++14

I have checked out the related posts to this error and wasn't able to use those solutions to solve my problem. So i have this code that attempts to dynamically create a tuple by converting stringified values to their corresponding types in the array for that I have a generic function that aims to produce that value and add it to the tuple but it seems to be throwing an error whenever I try to generically set its return type.

This the generic function that converts the stringified argument into its actual type
(its just a minimal exmaple btw not the whole function i have written in my codebase).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T convertArg(string type, string arg)
{   
    if (type == "Integer") {
        int temp = stoi(arg);
        return temp;
    } else if (type == "Boolean") {
        return arg == "true" ? true : false;
    } else {
        return arg;
    }
};
```

I have a runtime loop that creates the tuple by using the function above.

```
namespace detail
{
    template <int... Is>
    struct seq
    {
    };

    template <int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
    {
    };

    template <int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>
    {
    };
    template <typename... Ts, int... Is>
    tuple<Ts...> for_each(tuple<Ts...> &t, std::vector<string> types, std::vector<string> args, seq<Is...>)
    {
// this line throws the error where i try set the return type of the function on the basis of the element at that index in the tuple.
        return make_tuple(convertArg<tuple_element<Is, decltype(t)>::type>(types.at(Is), args.at(Is))...);
    }
}

template <typename... Ts>
tuple<Ts...> for_each_in_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...> &t, std::vector<string> types, std::vector<string> args)
{
    return detail::for_each(t, types, args, detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> types = {"String", "Integer"};
    std::vector<std::string> args = {"rehan", "12"};
    std::tuple<std::string, int> t;
    t = for_each_in_tuple(t, types, args);
    cout << "Tuple values" << endl;
    cout << get<0>(t) << endl;
    cout << get<1>(t) << endl;
}
```

The complete error as well:

```
main.cpp:41:38: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<std::string, int> &>'
        return make_tuple(convertArg<tuple_element<Is, decltype(t)>::type>(types.at(Is), args.at(Is))...);
```

I've already looked at the other solution and it didnt work for me and thats why i have asked this question to get a solution related to my particular scenario and btw im on c++ 14

Comment: Always post complete error in your question description.

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are all the `#include`s?

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of reinventing the wheel, use [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) instead of `gen_seq`.

Comment: I updated the question and added the include statements and the complete error and its not a duplicate Ive already looked at the opther question

Comment: Unrelated 2: Instead of `return arg == "true" ? true : false;` just make it `return arg == "true";`

Comment: Related/dupe: [error: no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int>::tuple()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78008000/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdtuplestdvectorint-stdalloca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `decltype(t)` it should be `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t)>` but that just leads to the next problem, your `convertArg` function will not work. All branches must be valid and if `T` is `std::string` returning `int` isn't valid for example.

I suggest that you drop the `vector` with *types* and just use the information in the `tuple`:

```cpp
template <class T> // primary, just let the string through
T convertArg(const std::string& arg) {
    return arg;
}

template <> // specialization for int
int convertArg<int>(const std::string& arg) {
    return stoi(arg);
}
template <> // specialization for bool
bool convertArg<bool>(const std::string& arg) {
    return arg == "true";
}

namespace detail {
template <typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<Ts...> for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& t,
                           const std::vector<std::string>& args,
                           std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return make_tuple(
        convertArg<
            std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t)>>>(
            args.at(Is))...);
}
}  // namespace detail

template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> for_each_in_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& t,
                                    const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
    return detail::for_each(t, args, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
}
```

`std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t)>` could also be replaced with `std::tuple<Ts...>`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YhM5dTYbe)